# Importance of ASLR Mode 2

Tags: linux, aslr

From what I understand, ASLR has 3 Modes:

- **0** - turned off
- **1** - randomizes stack, heap, shared libraries, vDSO, mmap memory area and text area (if built with -fPIE -pie)
- **2** - additionally randomizes `brk()`-allocated memory, which comes, to my understanding, mostly from small `malloc()`-calls.

Why is there an extra mode especially for `brk()`-allocated memory (if this is really all it does) and how important is it or rather when is it important to use Mode 2 of ASLR instead of Mode 1?

Comment: Linux man page http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/brk.2.html has a warning to not use brk(). Therefore, brk() not being a default would justify having a separate mode for ASLR.

Comment: It does indeed say brk() should  be avoided. Yet the [man page of malloc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) states that it uses sbrk(), so i'd guess that it is used a lot, maybe without everybody being aware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be a specific way of randomizing `brk()` as well, as there are some heap implementations other than glibc's default (ptmalloc) that might not rely on `brk()`, leaving direct use of `brk()` unprotected to predictable address space if only `va_randomize_space = 1` is used.

This is also important because attackers could craft shellcodes using direct `SYS_brk` system calls to map memory with a predicted address space to work on.

A quick look into the Linux kernel source code suggests setting ASLR to mode 2 does only just that: randomizes the start of the dynamic memory mapping address space:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L1110-L1123

```
<!-- language: lang-c -->

    if ((current->flags & PF_RANDOMIZE) && (randomize_va_space > 1)) {
        /*
         * For architectures with ELF randomization, when executing
         * a loader directly (i.e. no interpreter listed in ELF
         * headers), move the brk area out of the mmap region
         * (since it grows up, and may collide early with the stack
         * growing down), and into the unused ELF_ET_DYN_BASE region.
         */
        if (IS_ENABLED(CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_ELF_RANDOMIZE) &&
            elf_ex->e_type == ET_DYN && !interpreter) {
            mm->brk = mm->start_brk = ELF_ET_DYN_BASE;
        }

        mm->brk = mm->start_brk = arch_randomize_brk(mm);
#ifdef compat_brk_randomized
        current->brk_randomized = 1;
#endif
    }
```

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/mmap.c#L212-L213

```
<!-- language: lang-c -->

    if (current->brk_randomized)
        min_brk = mm->start_brk;
```

Comment: Thank you, that sheds some more light on this.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help!